# UrlLauncher( 9700): component name for mailto is null

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, url-launcher

So I know that for android version >= 30 you need to add queries in the manifest, but this didnt do the trick for me.
Im using Android Version 29. I nevertheless added these lines to my manifest.

So my manifest looks like this.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I managed to reproduce the error for my machine with the code bellow. Nevertheless I get this error:

> I/UrlLauncher(10601): component name for mailto:?subject=&body= is null

Down below you find the code for main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () => launchEmail(
            toEmail: "js",
            subject: "dm",
            message: "jd",
          ), child: Text("null"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future launchEmail({
    required String toEmail,
    required String subject,
    required String message,
  }) async {
    final url =
        "mailto:$toEmail?subject=${Uri.encodeFull(subject)}&body=${Uri.encodeFull(message)}";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so i was having similar error i just added package name of app that i wanted to use  `<package android:name="com.app" />` also did u add that in manifest of debug not release?

Comment: I updated my Android API version to 30+ & now it works 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I did to resolve the error:

I set my Android API to 30+

Your manifest.xml should contains this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

If this doesnt fix it for you, Suj suggested to add:

```
<package android:name="com.app" />
```

to your manifest

So just paste the lines under the start of your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nikita.autolab">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
   <application
        android:label="AutoLab"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I just had to add the node

<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent>

to my manifest file, since I already had the two previous entries. now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

#### By updating your API to 30 (`minSdkVersion`), you are restricting the devices and Android versions which can install your app.

###### Alternative solution: Don't call `canLaunch` for `mailto` links - use it only for `http` and `https`!

Since I have both `http(s)` and `mailto` links in my app, I use the `try-catch` block.

Here is the full function:

```dart
class UrlHandler {
  /// Attempts to open the given [url] in in-app browser. Returns `true` after successful opening, `false` otherwise.
  static Future<bool> open(String url) async {
    try {
      await launch(
        url,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: launch is deprecated.

Comment: @MarceloJuanCabreraGutierrez what do you suggest me to do? this was written almost 6 months ago, let me know if I can do anything to make it better.

Comment: @Aleksandar To put it simply, do not check using canLaunchUrl() when it comes to sending email. I experienced the same thing too, canLaunchUrl() reported that Uri cannot be launched, but it's wrong, I can launch gmail just fine! When I simply run launchUrl()!